# I have lots of errors in appcompat_v7 folder

Tags: android, eclipse

I am very new to android developing, and as soon as I created my first app
I got a lots of problems (errors) on this path **workspace\appcompat_v7\res** especially on **workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-...\styles_base.xml** and **workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-...\styles_rtl.xml** and one other error in **workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar**

here is some of my console errors

```
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] 
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7] C:\Users\Zakaria Sbaiy\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-14 12:17:06 - appcompat_v7]
```

and the eclipse said that The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved, I tried fixing this errors one after another but no use, that's why I am locking now for a way to change this **appcompat_v7** folder entirely with a clean one so it will be no further errors.

Is that possible ?

Comment: If you've edited various /res files and can't remember how to go back to the original files then the only way to start again with a clean support library is to use SDK Manager. Scroll down to Extras and select the Support Library and click the button saying "Uninstall 1 package". Let uninstall, close SDK Manager and eclipse then restart eclipse and go back to SDK Manager and reinstall the Support Library. To prevent the errors in /res, right-click the appcompat_v7 project and select Properties then Android and change the target to be API 21. Click OK then Clean and Build the library project.

Comment: sorry if this sound stupid but how do I Clean and Build the library project?

Comment: Select it then go to Project menu in eclipse - there should be an oplion for Clean. If you have Build Automatically setting then it will do it for you. If you don't have that setting then the Clean popup will give you the option to do it after the project as been cleaned.

Comment: Done and the errors vanished, thank You so much.

Comment: I've converted my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you've edited various /res files and can't remember how to go back to the original files then the only way to start again with a clean support library is to use SDK Manager.

Start SDK Manager and scroll down to "Extras" and select the "Support Library" and click the button saying "Uninstall 1 package". Let it uninstall then close SDK Manager and eclipse. Restart eclipse and go back to SDK Manager and reinstall the Support Library.

To prevent the errors in /res, right-click the appcompat_v7 project and select Properties then  select Android and change the target to be API 21 then click OK.

You may need to Clean and Build the library project. To do this, select it then go to Project menu in eclipse - there should be an option for Clean. If you have the "Build Automatically" option set then it will do it for you. If you don't have that option set then the "Clean" popup will give you the option to do it after the project as been cleaned.